# Scrollable canvas containing imges in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8 app. I have a canvas containing images which I can drag to change their position in canvas. My problem is that canvas is not scrollable, I want a vertical scrollbar in page. I tried like this

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scvImages" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                <Canvas x:Name="canImages" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>                      
        </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like there's nothing telling the `ScrollViewer` to invoke since your `Grid` and `Canvas` are just going to fill the `ViewPort` so you might consider setting a fixed `Height` or something on your `Grid`

Comment: Thanks for reply. How I can fix height because I don't know how many images will user select.

Comment: Well when you add them to the Canvas currently, do they just stack on top of each other as they're added?

Comment: they stack in horizontal way

Comment: Well if you're doing it in a Canvas, you must be manually adding a left Margin or something then to position them right? Instead maybe populate them in a StackPanel or GridView so they still take up the provided space both left and right and then populate overflow below the viewable stuff, that would invoke your ScrollViewer also.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the height of your panel (canvas, grid, whatewer) which you want to scroll. Otherwise it will render out of the screen but 'thinks' that it is ok and scrolling is no needed (since it is infinite height).